# How to find out how many documents were omitted by find due to the limit option?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I search a MongoDB collection using the [`find(...,limit=10000,...)`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=collections%20find#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) method and I get the 10k documents I requested.

**Is there a cheap way to *estimate* how many documents would have been found without the `limit` argument?**

One obvious method is [`count_documents`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=collections%20find#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents), but I suspect it would be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: How about using `estimated_document_count` instead? It's the next method in the documentation you linked.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Thanks. Alas, that method returns the estimated _total_ number of documents, instantaneously, regardless of the `filter` argument.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `count_documents` is "fast enough".

It actually has a [`maxTimeMS`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS) argument which specifies

> maximum amount of time to allow this operation to run, in milliseconds

Alas, when this maximum is reached, you get

> ExecutionTimeout: Error in $cursor stage :: caused by :: errmsg: "operation exceeded time limit"

instead of an estimate of the document count (which it easily could -- using the number of matches so far, the number of documents seen so far, and [`estimated_document_count`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=collections%20find#pymongo.collection.Collection.estimated_document_count)).

This is, apparently, because `maxTimeMS` is a cursor-level option which has to have a consistent behavior across all uses of a cursor.